# submit data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, postdata

I need to post/submit  data from the source workbook  to the destination workbook(id) > worksheet

I have achieved this task by using the below code, but I need help posting to a different workbook > worksheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of the target spreadsheet').getSheetByName("DataSheet")
```

[openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)